# i'm connecting MySQL with hibernate annotation and getting following

Tags: mysql, hibernate

INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4

Comment: What is your question? Please also post some more context so that people can understand what may be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is essentially telling you it is not going to support large object creation because the JDBC driver you're using for MySQL doesn't support it since it is JDBC 3 compliant and not JDBC 4.

So long as you don't use LOB data types, the message is harmless.

If you need LOB support, you then need to consider using a different JDBC driver that is JDBC 4 compliant.